# DirectX and DirectXTK translation limits

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d

I use [DirectX Toolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) to display a 3d model, following the '[Rendering the model](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Rendering-a-model)' and my pyramid is displayed:

[image]

When trying to transform the object, the scaling and rotation work well but I'm not sure how to move the object (translate) around. Basically I'm looking for an algorithm that determines, given the current camera position, focus, viewport and the rendered model (which the DirectX toolkit gives me the bounding box so it's "size") the minimum and maximum values for XYZ translation so the object remains visible.

The bounding box is always the same, no matter the view port size, so how do I compare it's size against my viewport?

Please excuse my newbiness, I'm not a 3D developer, at least yet.

The "Simple Rendering" example which draws a triangle:

```
Matrix proj = Matrix::CreateScale( 2.f/float(backBufferWidth),
   -2.f/float(backBufferHeight), 1.f)
   * Matrix::CreateTranslation( -1.f, 1.f, 0.f );
m_effect->SetProjection(proj);
```

says that the normalized triangle size is [1,1,1]  but here normalized values do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL:DR:** To move your model around the world, create a matrix for the translation and set it as the world matrix with `SetWorld`.

```
Matrix world = Matrix::CreateTranslation( 2.f, 1.f, 3.f);
m_effect->SetWorld(world);

// Also be sure you have called SetView and SetProjection for the 3D camera setup
//covered in the 3D shapes / Rendering a model tutorial
```

You should start with a basic review of 3D transformations, in particular the **world** -> **view** -> **projection** transformation pipeline.

1. The **world** transformation performs the affine transformation to get the model you are rendering into it's 'world' position. (a.k.a. 'local coordinates to world coordinates transformation').
2. The **view** transformation performs the transformation to get world positions into the camera's point of view (i.e. position and direction) (a.k.a. 'world coordinates to view coordinates transformation').
3. The **projection** transformation performs the transformation to get the view positions into the canonical "-1 to 1" range that the actual hardware uses, including any perspective projection (a.k.a. 'view coordinates to 'clip' coordinates transformation).
4. The hardware itself performs the final step of converting the "-1 to 1" to pixel locations in the render target based on the Direct3D `SetViewport` information (a.k.a. 'clip' coordinates to pixel coordinates transformation).

> [This Direct3D 9 era article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/the-direct3d-transformation-pipeline) is a bit dated, but it covers the overall idea well.

In the *DirectX Tool Kit* BasicEffect system, there are distinct methods for each of these matrices: `SetWorld`, `SetView`, and `SetProjection`. There is also a helper if you want to set all three at once `SetMatrices`.

The [simple rendering](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Simple-rendering) tutorial is concerned with the simplest form of rendering, 2D rendering, where you want the coordinates you provide to be in natural 'pixel coordinates'

```
Matrix proj = Matrix::CreateScale( 2.f/float(backBufferWidth),
   -2.f/float(backBufferHeight), 1.f)
   * Matrix::CreateTranslation( -1.f, 1.f, 0.f );
m_effect->SetProjection(proj);
```

The purpose of this matrix is to basically 'undo' what the `SetViewport` will do so that you can think in simple pixel coordinates. It's *not* suitable for 3D models.

In the [3D shapes](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/3D-shapes) tutorial I cover the basic camera model, but I leave the *world* matrix as the identity so the shape is sitting at the world origin.

```
m_view = Matrix::CreateLookAt(Vector3(2.f, 2.f, 2.f),
    Vector3::Zero, Vector3::UnitY);
m_proj = Matrix::CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(XM_PI / 4.f,
    float(backBufferWidth) / float(backBufferHeight), 0.1f, 10.f);
```

In the [Rendering a model](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Rendering-a-model) tutorial, I also leave the world matrix as identity. I get into the basics of this in [Basic game math](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Basic-game-math) tutorial.

> One of the nice properties of [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) is that you can perform them all at once by transforming by the concatenation of the individual transforms. Point p transformed by matrix W, then transformed by matrix V, then transformed by matrix P is the same as point p transformed by matrix `W * V * P`.