# Setting up projection and model matrices for 2D rendering with DirectX(or any other graphics api)

Tags: matrix, 2d, rendering, directx

I am having trouble making the projection matrix to translate pixel space coordinates into screen space because if you're drawing a proper box in screen space it's going to be affected by window/screen aspect ratio thus become stretched. I honestly don't care which coordinate space I am going to end up with what I am looking for is to have 1:1 aspect ratio between coordinates and screen i.e {.5f, .5f} {1.f, 1.f} or {25, 25} {75, 75} would result in a perfect box shape, not stretched.

Screen aspect ratio can be fixed (but making it a 1:1 (box) ratio does not count)
This theoretically applies to any rendering api not only d3d

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67792814/directx-and-directxtk-translation-limits?rq=1) that shows the projection matrix you need to rescale the viewport transformation into pixel space.

Comment: Hello. What you're trying to feed me is a **related** answer. I have a very precise requirement of translating 2D shape with understandable coordinates, not squashing a 3D model into ortho and moving it around.